# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetRegistry' in '/home/hodzhakhov/project/plugin/node_modules/expo-asset/build'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, craco

I wrote Chrome Extensions, which gets App.tsx, and writes it to index.tsx. I'm trying to collect all this with the help of Craco and I get this error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetRegistry' in '/home/hodzhakhov/project/plugin/node_modules/expo-asset/build'.
Moreover, all modules are installed in node_modules

Here is the file craco.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const rootPath = path.join(__dirname, '..');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
            return {
                ...webpackConfig,
                entry: {
                    main: [env === 'development' &&
                        require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
                    paths.appIndexJs].filter(Boolean),
                },
                output: {
                    ...webpackConfig.output,
                    filename: 'static/js/[name].js',
                },
                optimization: {
                    ...webpackConfig.optimization,
                    runtimeChunk: false,
                },
            }
        },
    },
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "plugin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false craco build",
    "start": "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false craco start"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.253",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-valtio": "^0.6.2",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "firebase": "^10.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.14.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.9",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-batched-subscribe": "^0.1.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "valtio": "^1.11.2"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Error in file AssetRegistry.js
Could not find a declaration file for module '@react-native/assets-registry/registry'. '/home/hodzhakhov/work/project/plugin/node_modules/@react-native/assets-registry/registry.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Also in the @react-native/assets-registry/registry file.js VS Code also throws an error Type aliases can only be used in TypeScript files.

I tried to do what VS Code suggests: Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-native__assets-registry` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@react-native/assets-registry/registry';` But it didn't help